# jar throws errors from java project which works just fine

Tags: java, file, command-line, jar, apache-poi

I have made a little project, which I try to convert into exe file now. And to do so I need to make a jar file first, where the problems arise:

Here is what jar program throws.

```
C:> C:\[path]\IdeaProjects\Erpegkraj\out\artifacts\Erpegkraj_jar\Erpegkraj.jar
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Erpegkraj.Grafika.MenuGłówne.<init>(MenuGłówne.java:26)
        at Erpegkraj.PanelGry.<init>(PanelGry.java:63)
        at Erpegkraj.Interfejs.main(Interfejs.java:39)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file input stream from file: 'zasoby\Dane\Dane.xlsx'
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:188)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:175)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:285)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:192)
        at Erpegkraj.ZarządcaArkuszów.przeczytajWierszArkusza(ZarządcaArkuszów.java:24)
        at Erpegkraj.Postacie.Bohater.<init>(Bohater.java:39)
        at Erpegkraj.Postacie.Bohaterowie.Krzyżowiec.<init>(Krzyżowiec.java:13)
        at Erpegkraj.Grafika.DaneWMenu.Bohaterowie$1.evaluate(Bohaterowie.java:15)
        at Erpegkraj.Grafika.DaneWMenu.Bohaterowie.<clinit>(Bohaterowie.java:20)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: zasoby\Dane\Dane.xlsx (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:185)
        ... 11 more
```

It keeps saying that it can't open a file (an excel file) in my resources folder (which is called zasoby).

This is a part of code I think it has problems with:

```
public static String readSheetsLine(File sheetsPath, String sheetsName, String name) throws IOException {
    String text = "";
    OPCPackage package;
    Workbook wb;
    try {
        package = OPCPackage.open(sheetsPath);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(package);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetsName);

    for(Row r: sheet){
        String value = r.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        if(Objects.equals(value, nazwa)){
            for (Cell c : r){
                c.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                String typ = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(c.getColumnIndex()).getStringCellValue();
                if (!Objects.equals(typ, "")){
                    tekst += typ + "#"+ c.getStringCellValue()+"~";
                }else break;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (Objects.equals(value, "")) break;
    }
    wb.close();
    package.close();
    return text;
}
```

I have tried everything I could find on the Internet about  "InvalidOperationException", but nothing prevailed.

I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: One you build a jar, a file in your resources folder is an entry in the jar, not an actual file. You need to access is as a class path resource, not a file system file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the **absolute path**?

```
File sheetsPath = new File("zasoby\\Dane\\Dane.xlsx");
String absolutePath = sheetsPath.getAbsolutePath();
package = OPCPackage.open(new File(absolutePath));
```

Or try to use **ClassPathrecourses** but it is from **Spring**

```
InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("zasoby/Dane/Dane.xlsx").getInputStream();
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);
```

If the Excel file is included in your JAR (in the resources folder), you should load it from the classpath rather than using a file path.

```
InputStream stream = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("zasoby/Dane/Dane.xlsx");
package = OPCPackage.open(stream);
```

here is another way to achieve the result from Java

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("zasoby/Dane/Dane.xlsx")
```

I hope this is somewhat useful.

Comment: Where is `ClassPathResource`from?  Not part of standard Java, so better mention it (Spring?)

Comment: I would also like to know, where ClassPathResource is from, because nothing else you had proposed, didn't work.

Comment: @user85421 Sorry here where it comes from
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource